# TypeScript dynamic module loading issue with typeof

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, require, typeof

I am dynamically loading modules I have created like so:

myModule.ts

```
export class SomeClass {
 ...
}
export type SomeType = {...}
```

In another file, I do:

```
import * as MyModuleType from "./myModule"
if(...) {
  let loadedModule: typeof MyModuleType = require("./myModule");
  ...
}
```

The type of MyModuleType has both SomeClass and SomeType (as expected). Whereas the type of loadedModule has only SomeClass (incomplete type!). How can I solve this issue?

Version of typescript: 2.3.2

editor: atom, using atom-typescript v10.1.15

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Types in TS descripe values. so `typeof MyModuleType` describes the shape of the module value at run time. The module value only has one property, i.e. `SomeClass`. And it does not have any property `SomeType`.

If you want to get the type jsut reference the import:

```js
var x: MyModuleType.SomeType;
```

The TS compiler still knows that your import is only used as a type and will be elided.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what you said works if the import statements and the dynamic require statement are in one file. What if I want to pass loadedModule to another file, and I want to do so without having an import * as .... statement in that file. How will I then get "SomeType" access via loadedModule?